# How to use aggregation transformation in azure logic app?

Tags: odata, aggregation, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure Logic App to fetch list of records from Azure SQL Database. I am using odata filter to solve my problem. It all works good when I pass the $filter, $select and other parameters like below

[My Logic App Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSs70.png)

I would like to use Aggregation Transformation in this. But it is now working. In aggregation transformation I have used the below syntax
groupby((Name), aggregate(ID with countdistinct as Total))

can someone help me how I can use aggregation transformation in Azure Logic App?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a query that was written incorrectly. We have GroupBy and Aggregates in the Aggregate Transformations, therefore we must mention them separately, just as we would in conventional SQL.

One of the workarounds is that when I simply mention the query in the 'Execute a SQL query(v2)' connector, I was able to extract data from a sql database applying aggregate functions as well.

Below is the query I'm using, which includes `group by` and `sum` aggregate.

```
SELECT
department_id, SUM(salary)
FROM
employees
GROUP BY department_id;
```

The screenshot of my logic app is shown below.
[image]

and here is the output that I received in logic apps

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
        "x-ms-request-id": "8407b5c5-ba6a-49ad-8709-39890f9a7dcd",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
        "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
        "Date": "Thu, 21 Oct 2021 10:46:21 GMT",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata.metadata=minimal",
        "Expires": "-1",
        "Content-Length": "401"
    },
    "body": {
        "ResultSets": {
            "Table1": [
                {
                    "department_id": 1,
                    "": 4400
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 2,
                    "": 19000
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 3,
                    "": 24900
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 4,
                    "": 6500
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 5,
                    "": 41200
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 6,
                    "": 28800
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 7,
                    "": 10000
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 8,
                    "": 57700
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 9,
                    "": 58000
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 10,
                    "": 51600
                },
                {
                    "department_id": 11,
                    "": 20300
                }
            ]
        },
        "OutputParameters": {}
    }
}
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [SQL GROUP BY: How To Apply It Effectively (sqltutorial.org)](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-group-by/)
2. [Azure Data Factory – Aggregate transformation in mapping data flow – Tech-Tutes](https://tech-tutes.com/2021/07/12/azure-data-factory-aggregate-transformation-in-mapping-data-flow/)
3. [Aggregator Transformation - javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/aggregator-transformation)